# Access denied on folders for users though they have the rwx permission on SUSE Linux

Tags: linux, ubuntu, permissions, acl, suse

I have a folder /PPI/production/PDF_plan/ on SLES 12 SP1 system. Please find the details below.

```
SERVER1:~ # getfacl /PPI/production/PDF_plan/
getfacl: Removing leading '/' from absolute path names
# file: PPI/production/PDF_plan/
# owner: ppi
# group: ppi
user::rwx
group::r-x
other::r-x
```

Then I gave rwx permission for a group called **AdCNC** as below

```
SERVER1:~ # setfacl -Rdm g:AdCNC:rwx /PPI/production/PDF_plan/
SERVER1:~ #
```

**ncaps1** is a user under **AdCNC** group.

```
SERVER1:~ # grep ncaps1 /etc/group
AdCNC:x:1005:ncaps1
SERVER1:~ #
```

Please find below the getfacl output on this folder now. It clearly shows that **AdCNC** group now has the rwx permission on this folder.

```
SERVER1:~ #
SERVER1:~ # getfacl /PPI/production/PDF_plan/
getfacl: Removing leading '/' from absolute path names
# file: PPI/production/PDF_plan/
# owner: ppi
# group: ppi
user::rwx
group::r-x
other::r-x
default:user::rwx
default:group::r-x
default:group:AdCNC:rwx
default:mask::rwx
default:other::r-x
```

But When I try to create a folder or write a file on /PPI/production/PDF_plan/ I am getting 'access denied' error message.

```
SERVER1:~ # su ncaps1
ncaps1@SERVER1:/root> cp /Ran/ExistingConfiguration/smb.conf /PPI/production/PDF_plan/
cp: cannot create regular file ‘/PPI/production/PDF_plan/smb.conf’: Permission denied
ncaps1@SERVER1:/root> mkdir /PPI/production/PDF_plan/TestFolder 
mkdir: cannot create directory ‘/PPI/production/PDF_plan/TestFolder’: Permission denied
ncaps1@SERVER1:/root>
```

Please help me to fix this problem. Thank you

Comment: Please note that Stackoverflow is for programming related questions only. Please review the [help/on-topic] for what topics can be asked here. This question may be appropriate on other SE sites such as [unix.se]. Check their help first to see if the question belongs there and if so you can click the "flag" link and select "in need of moderator attention" to request migration there.

Comment: Thanks @kaylum. I have posted this question on Unix & Linux

Answer (score 0, accepted):

default:group:AdCNC:rwx is not permission of AdCNC in this folder, it means that the permission "rwx" fro AdCNC for sub folders which will be created in future.

Let's run (without -d option):

setfacl -Rm g:AdCNC:rwx /PPI/production/PDF_plan/